# Download file from SFTP using VBA and URLDownloadToFile

Tags: vba, excel, sftp

Our ftp server just migrated to an sftp server. A workbook that several of us share uses vba to download the files. I changed the url to the new sftp url and now it won't download. Is URLDownloadToFile compatible with SFTP?

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

sub ftp()
URLDownloadToFile 0, _
        "sftp://username:P)O(i4b6@sftp.st.gov/internet/in/201711_80.1035", _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\FTP\File1.txt", 0, 0
end sub
```

Comment: No; WinInet, upon which that call sits, does not support SFTP. You would need a 3rd party component/tool

Comment: Do you have any kind of console or GUI with it that may have an API?